# Best town to live and work over the Internet in Sicily / Italy

Tags: work, italy, sicily

Two questions:

1. Which city would you choose based on my preferences?
2. What's the availability of internet and its fees?

A relative on my parents' side is from Sicily. I have relatives in all of the following cities:

**Palermo, Catania, Messina, Siracusa, Marsala, Gela, Ragusa, Trapani, Vittoria, Bagheria, Modica**

My preferences are: climate (the hotter the better), people (I like typical friendly attitude), city (I like old romantic cities more than modern ones), average age of the people (I am 29), infrastructure, beaches and some nightlife.

Since I will be working there over the internet, the reliability and fees for internet connection are an additional major preference. What can be said about that? Which providers and which conditions (flatline, wireless, cable, up/download rate) would you recommend?

thanks for your advice.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately if you check our [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) you'll see we can't accept this question for a couple of reasons: **1)** It's an immigration/expat question **2)** It's totally subjective - there is no "correct" answer, only opinions. Stack Exchange is about Q & A rather than recommendations. You might consider following [the proposed site on immigration](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10331/immigration) though, and maybe even ask this question there as an example.

Comment: @hippietrail i am only living in sicily for 3 months (during winter). but thx for your correction if it might be appropriate. the availability of internet access varies in sicily, i don't think thats subjective. also the providers can be divergent based on facts. there are cities in sicily which are more ancient, have better public infrastructure, etc. some cities, specialy those with universities, have younger people living there. i don't think thats a subjective question neither. all the answer can be given based on facts.

Comment: @hippietrail's right - it's subjective.  "Which city would you choose?" is always going to be subjective.  What constitutes friendly people? You may be 29, but do you want 29 year olds, or do you want younger people? Do you like sand or stone beaches, swimming or sunbathing beaches? Anyway, it's certainly something that will do well on the immigration beta, and hopefully it starts up soon! :)